# Flash Browser? Flash Server Side?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have two noobish questions about Flash, Actionscript, Flex etc.

1) With these technologies is it possible to create a simple web browser that can render websites?

2) Is it possible to run these technologies on the server side? I am guessing no as Flash requires a browser to run within?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML in Flash**

Technically you can write an HTML rendering engine in Flash.  DENG is an old project that did exactly this.  I don't think it's still be updated though.

http://osflash.org/deng

Adobe AIR supports rendering HTML in the embedded WebKit based engine within Flash.

**Flash on server**

The standalone Flash Player can be used on the server and is often used for unit testing within a continuous integration environment.  When run from a background service I don't think it will actually display a UI, but it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this article http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/articles/air_browser_sample_application.html - it describes how to build your browser with Flash/Air (running on the desktop)